# In Electron, evaluate a menu item's state when menu is opened

Tags: javascript, electron

**TL;DR**: I need to check whether to disable or enable a menu item each time the containing menu is opened. How should I do it?

**Details**: In an Electron app's main menu I have a menu item that should only be enabled when the user has certain kind of data in the clipboard - think of it as a specific kind of paste function.

Accessing the clipboard and evaluating the data's validity is easy, but I can't find a way to perform the evaluation only when the menu containing this particular item is opened.

The data will be coming from outside my app, so I could check the clipboard's contents whenever the window's focus event fires. Another option would be to do polling. Neither is very elegant, and I'm hoping for a more sensible approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electron exposes the menu control via the [menu.SetApplicationMenu(menu) function](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/menu/#menusetapplicationmenumenu).

Listening for the window.focus event and setting this menu via the remote module everytime the event triggers should enable you to achieve the desired functionality:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<script>
const {remote} = require('electron');
const {Menu, MenuItem} = remote;

const menu = new Menu();
menu.append(new MenuItem({label: 'MenuItem1', click() { console.log('item 1 clicked'); }}));


window.addEventListener('focus', (e) => {   remote.setApplicationMenu(menu); }, true);

</script>
```

See the [electron menu API](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/menu/) for more info and the code snippet the above one is based on. I haven't actually tested the code, but it should outline a solution.

**Additional Information regarding possible future solutions:**

As of End of June 2016, there are two possible solutions down the line that are currently under development by the electron dev team:

1. A new event might be introduced which is triggered on changes in the clipboard ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2280))
2. Dynamic menus are a possible focus in the current development ([Github issue](http://github.com/electron/electron/issues/528))

Comment: This is indeed one way to do it, but it doesn't guarantee the data is still valid when the menu is opened.

Comment: That's true. However, the Electron clipboard api doesn't have a change event ([yet, here is an open issue on this topic](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2280)) and the menu api doesn't have one for onOpen ... this kind of restricts your options to diff-checking the current clipboard to it's previous content in some interval, which really is less than desirable in any case.

Comment: In addition to the clipboard onchange event, I found another github issue on electron concerning dynamic menus that seems to be a possible future fix for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I think that's the "most correct" way to solve it, so I guess I'll just have to wait, and use a workaround in the mean time. If you could edit the link to your answer, I'll mark it as accepted and award the bounty.

Comment: Done, glad I could help!